# How to clear all the values using ctrl+Z after numer being typed in angula8 using ngx-mask

Tags: angular, ngx-mask

mask for phone number field but here if i type some numbers and do ctrl+Z, it is not clearing all the values, when i do ctrlZ after typing, it must clear all the values present in it.

DEMO:
[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-vs-template-with-ngx-mask-ucxyu6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

TS:

```
this.eoInfoForm = this.FB.group({
      amount: ['', Validators.required],
    });
```

HTML:

```
 <input [formControl]="eoInfoForm.control['amount']" mask='(000)-000-0000'><br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding an input, keyup.control.z and keyup.enter listener and combining it with a history array.

You can view this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-vs-template-with-ngx-mask-1stm9r) to see it working.

Comment: Thanks, it is working but if i get any doubts i will ping you back